# Interpoloation algorithm for image smoothing - Angular 12 environment

Tags: angular, image-processing, html5-canvas, bicubic

I am working on implementing a ***bicubic interpolation*** function (within our Angular application) in order to "*smooth*" an image upon zooming. Without it the image becomes very pixelated on zoom.

I have it working in the **StackBlitz** online project (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bga9dz?file=src/app/app.component.ts), but NOT in our application -and I can't figure out why.

In this application code sample below - the `mousewheel` scroll event fires zoom(), which calls redraw().

In `redraw()`, I create a hidden canvas, put the bicubic `results` to it, then draw to main `ctx0` canvas context. But the image is still pixelated, as if the `results` array has no affect.

```js
handleScroll(that: ImageViewerComponent, evt: MouseWheel, fromAction?: boolean): boolean {
   that.zoom(delta, evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY);
}

zoom(clicks: number, mouseX: number, mouseY: number): void {
        const oldWidth: number = this.cw;
        const oldHeight: number = this.ch;

        this.totalClicks = this.totalClicks + clicks;

        const factor: number = Math.pow(this.scaleFactor, clicks);
        this.cx = this.sx + this.cw / 2; // current x
        this.cy = this.sy + this.ch / 2; // curreny y
        this.cw = this.cw * factor; // current width
        this.ch = this.ch * factor; // current height

        this.saveCX = this.cx;
        this.saveCY = this.cy;
        this.saveCW = this.cw;
        this.saveCH = this.ch;

        // Don't zoom if the image is either too small or too large.
        this.ctx0.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

        // Coordinates of the mouse relative to the image, with the origin being the top-left.
        const relativeMouseX: number = mouseX - this.sx;
        const relativeMouseY: number = mouseY - this.sy;

        this.sx += (relativeMouseX / oldWidth) * (oldWidth - this.cw);
        this.sy += (relativeMouseY / oldHeight) * (oldHeight - this.ch);
        this.scaleX = this.cw / this.imageDimensions[0];
        this.scaleY = this.ch / this.imageDimensions[1];

        this.saveSX = this.sx;
        this.saveSY = this.sy;
        this.saveScaleX = this.scaleX;
        this.saveScaleY = this.scaleY;
        this.zoomSaved = true;

        this.redraw(true);
}
    
redraw(isZooming = false): void {

    this.clearStage(); // reassign the this.ctx0 context. run a clearRect()/setTransform()
    
    this.ctx0.drawImage(this.imageObj, this.sx, this.sy, this.cw, this.ch);

    if (this.imgType === 'bscan' && isZooming && this.useBicubicInterp) {
      const hiddenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      hiddenCanvas.width = this.ctx0.canvas.width;
      hiddenCanvas.height = this.ctx0.canvas.height;
      this.ctxHiddenZoomCanvas = hiddenCanvas.getContext('2d');
      this.ctxHiddenZoomCanvas.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

      const imageData = this.ctx0.getImageData(0, 0, this.canvasDimensions[0], this.canvasDimensions[1]);
      const dest = this.ctxHiddenZoomCanvas.createImageData(this.ctx0.canvas.width, this.ctx0.canvas.height);
      
      // BICUBIC CALL ! WRITE RESULTS TO CANVAS.
      let scale = 1.5;      
      const results = this.mediaService.bicubic(imageData, dest, scale);
      
      this.ctxHiddenZoomCanvas.putImageData(results, 0, 0);
      this.ctx0.drawImage(this.ctxHiddenZoomCanvas.canvas, this.sx, this.sy, this.cw, this.ch);
      }
    
}
```

**Further details -**

Normal image size (viewed in app, no smoothing, no zooming):

[image]

Zoomed in (via mouse wheel) and custom zooming code (canvas ***imageSmoothingEnabled = false***) -

[image]

We have tested the Html5 Canvas smoothing with **imageSmoothingEnabled**, and it does remove the pixelation on zoom. However, since it's not clear what algorithm Chrome uses (perhaps bilinear), we would like to implement the more advanced bicubic interpolation on our images.

E.g. with Canvas **imageSmoothingEnabled=true**, quality = ***'high'*** (notably smoother)

[image]

It's working in this online Stackblitz, but for some reason NOT working in our own application. Meaning, even after the bicubic results are written back to `ctx0` canvas context - the image is NOT smoothed at all. It remains pixelated. The question is why?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bga9dz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

UPDATE: the smoothing algorithm does appear to be applied to our canvas, however it appears to reposition the imageData each time with respect to the upper left hand corner. i.e. After applying our zoom function, we call `drawImage()` at those coordinates, then run the imageData it thru the smoothing algorithm, then `drawImage()` again. The smoothed image area is no longer where I expected it.

Comment: The improvement between nearest neighbor and bilinear interpolation is striking. That between bilinear and bicubic is barely noticeable.

Comment: Currently setting `imageSmoothingQuality = "high"` should use bicubic in Chrome (both for upscale and downscale). But they'll change it [in the near future](https://crbug.com/618324#c51), and currently it seems to have an effect only with Canvas image sources (at least on my macOS chromes).

Comment: @Kaiido - I could never figure out what interpolation method Chrome was using for the "high" quality setting, so I'm happy to have read the post you just linked to. As per that link " 'high' currently uses bicubic interpolation for both upscaling and downscaling".

Comment: @Kaiido - I was reading the spec at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-imagesmoothingquality-dev , specifically the Note section further down which reads "Bilinear scaling is an example of a relatively fast, lower-quality image-smoothing algorithm. Bicubic or Lanczos scaling are examples of image-smoothing algorithms that produce higher-quality output. This specification does not mandate that specific interpolation algorithms be used."

Comment: @bob.mazzo yes I know, the quote in your first comment is exactly what I paraphrased in mine and for the specs, I'm aware no specific algo is defined. FWIW, [it's been asked](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7697) 10 days ago and got declined by FF's implementers, but given the various discussions in Chrome bugs I can also imagine they'd be against it.

Comment: @Kaiido - so in the end, is it safe to say that (at this moment in CHROME) bicubic interpolation is in fact applied to the canvas when imageSmoothingEnabled=true and  imageSmothingQuality='high' ?

Comment: No it's not "safe" since they are considering changing it in the near future (second part of my first comment)